# Assign ng-model input value from a different object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form with input values assigned to an `ng-model` that i'm trying to assign pre-defined values with the `value` attribute:

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{oneevent.date}}"  ng-model="onebooking.date"/>
<input type="hidden" value="{{oneevent.title}}" ng-model="onebooking.name"/>
<input type="hidden" value="{{oneevent._id}}"   ng-model="onebooking.owner"/>
```

But is not working at all. The `oneevent` object exists in the same `$scope` as `onebooking`

---

When the user clicks the submit button, i want create a new booking, but i need get the properties `date`, `title` and `_id` from `oneevent`, for example:

```
<form class="expanded-form">
   <input type="hidden" value="{{oneevent.date}}"  ng-model="onebooking.date"/>
   <input type="hidden" value="{{oneevent.title}}" ng-model="onebooking.name"/>
   <input type="hidden" value="{{oneevent._id}}"   ng-model="onebooking.owner"/>
   <label class="expanded-label"> Nome: * </label>
   <input class="expanded-input" type="text" ng-model="onebooking.name">
   <label class="expanded-label"> E-mail: * </label>
   <input class="expanded-input" type="email" ng-model="onebooking.email">
   <label class="expanded-label"> Telefone: * </label>
   <input class="expanded-input" type="text" ng-model="onebooking.phone">
   <label class="expanded-label"> Participantes: * </label>
   <input class="expanded-input" type="number" min="1" ng-model="onebooking.participants">
   <label class="expanded-label"> Observações: (Opcional) </label>
   <textarea class="expanded-input" ng-model="onebooking.obs"></textarea>
</form>
```

When the user clicks the submit button I'll create a new `onebooking`, but there are three properties that I need to inherit from the `oneevent` that will own the `onebooking`

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't really understand the question. is `oneevent` inaccessible?

Comment: Is not inaccessible, but there are several oneevent's, i'm making a ng-repeat in the events = ng-repeat="oneevent in events", so i need assign some informations in specific onebooking's, get it?

Comment: Are these `onebooking`s children of the `oneevent`? How are they coupled? If they're children, couldn't you just use `oneevent.onebooking.propertyName`? Or rather `ng-model="oneevent.onebooking" ng-value="name"`

Comment: They are not. I need create onebooking when some user click in the submit button, but i need copy the properties date, title and _id from oneevent to onebooking, give me a sec, i will update my answer.

Comment: Oh, well then that sounds like logic that should be handled by your controller or a service or something. Which would create the `onebooking` object based on your `oneevent` and then store it on submit.

Comment: you want to compare both oneevent and onebooking right?

Comment: I want create onebooking inheriting the date, _id and title from oneevent, but there are several oneevents, i can't just get the first oneevent using $scope.oneevent[0].

Comment: @AmandaFerrari , i was given an example but that's not mean that you have to use first index.assign according to your need :)

Comment: What I'm trying to do is very simple and I do not need a controller to do so. Each form is created through repetition in an event array. These events have inputs that will make it possible to create bookings. When a user clicks the submit button ( make booking ) , I want to get the event information. Get it?

Comment: Aaah I think I get it now... Have you tried assigning it with `ng-init`? See http://jsfiddle.net/9anjjfbz/

Comment: My English is very bad for writing, but I can read perfectly. Sorry about that.

Comment: Yeap!!! Thats what i need @Jan, post as answer, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ng-init` to assign the value from another object/model

```
<input type="hidden" ng-init="onebooking.date=oneevent.date"  ng-model="onebooking.date"/>
<input type="hidden" ng-init="onebooking.name=oneevent.title" ng-model="onebooking.name"/>
<input type="hidden" ng-init="onebooking.owner=oneevent._id"   ng-model="onebooking.owner"/>
```

For an example of `ng-init` in action (not this exact code though) see http://jsfiddle.net/9anjjfbz/

Comment: Perfect! Thanks Jan and i'm sorry for my english :P.

Comment: No problem, you managed to get the message across in the end. :)

Comment: @AmandaFerrari I just noticed when editing your question to make it clearer, that you've defined `onebooking.name` twice, once for the event name and once for what I'm guessing is the name of the person doing the booking. You should rename one of those because my guess is right now they're conflicting.

Comment: Yes, i will! Thanks for the tip! :)

Comment: you should be aware, this is not the intended use for `ng-init`, and using it in this manner could cause unexpected, hard to debug errors.  `ng-init` is a directive, with a set priority, and it is possible that these values may not populate when you expect them to due to this priority.  unless you are trying to create an alias of an `ng-repeat` property that is already assigned at a higher priority (`$first`, `$last`, etc.) you should not use this method, and use a controller instead.  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit#!/

Answer (score 0):

Add to `$scope` from controller.

Comment: i can't, i'm using ng-repeat because there are several events and several forms.

Comment: i have several forms, and one form = onebooking, and in this booking i need get some informations from specific oneevent

Comment: Basically you want to compare both oneevent and onebooking. Do that in controller.

Answer (score 0):

I would fix it as follow:

In your Controller

```
$scope.submitFunction = function(oneevent, onebooking) {
    onebooking.date = oneevent.date;
    onebooking.name = oneevent.title;
    onebooking.owner = oneevent._id;

    // All other operations that you'll need to perform to submit

}
```

In Your html

```
<input type="submit" ng-click="submitFunction(oneevent, onebooking)">
```

Answer (score 0):

Write it in the model class itself where you are binding the values- Like i have binded the 'promoStartDate' to 'clawbackEffectiveDate'.

No change on the form input tag-

```
<input  type="date" name="clawbackEffectiveDate" class="form-control" value="{{promoModel.promoStartDate}}" style=" width: 80%" placeholder="Clawback Effective Date" [(ngModel)]=promoModel.clawbackEffectiveDate >
```

So now once you enter the promostartdate the value can be seen in the clawbackEffectiveDate input.

```
export class PromoModel {

  public promoStartDate: String;
  public clawbackEffectiveDate: String=this.promoStartDate;
}
```